# 2 ESXI hosts, only one with WAN incoming, no physical switch: how to have pfsense in Host #1 provide LAN to Host #2?

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

This might be a very beginner question, but wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

The following is a diagram of the physical servers (questions below it):

[image]

Both computers have ESXI and #1 has pfsense running in a VM. There no physical switch available to connect the hosts to.

**What is the optimal way to route all WAN through the pfsense VM and create a single LAN for all the VMs in BOTH hosts?**

Comment: Get a switch. Don't use your hypervisor as a router.

Comment: There's literally nothing remotely professional about this setup, it's riddled with lack of experience and bad practice - if this were for home use I'd still be worried but for professional environments it's borderline dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `LAN` port group on ESXi2, attached to NIC 2A. Connect a single vNIC on each client to this port group.

Create a `LAN` port group on ESXi1, attached to NIC 1B. Connect a single vNIC on the client VM to this port group.

Create a `WAN` port group on ESXi1, attached to NIC 1A. Create two vNICs for the pfSense VM and connect to both port groups.

I'm not quite sure how you're connecting to the servers to manage them though...